# On Windows, with C++, how to downlad files to a specific folder？

Tags: c++, directory, download

I want to download files by using the URLDownloadToFile Function, I download **a** file successfully with A pre-drafted name, such as test.jpg. But I can not download **two or more** files to a specific folder(Because you can't name two or more pictures with a name this time).So, can anybody help?
By the way, the next is my Test.cpp code:

```
// Test.cpp : Defines the entry point for the application.
//
#include <Windows.h>
#include <thread>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <Urlmon.h> //for URLDownloadToFile
#pragma comment(lib, "urlmon.lib")
#include <iostream>

void win_downLoad(std::vector<std::string>& urlVector )
{
    std::string downloadURL = "";
    int length = urlVector.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        downloadURL = urlVector[i];
        std::string savepath = "C:\\tmp\\" ;
        URLDownloadToFile(NULL, downloadURL.c_str(), savepath.c_str(), 0, NULL);
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> urlVector {"https://unsplash.com/photos/aoiUPcoLbBk/download?force=true", "https://unsplash.com/photos/0qGnW6iakaE/download?force=true",
    "https://unsplash.com/photos/fWDe78O7-Ks/download?force=true", "https://unsplash.com/photos/4c5Fovle5Dc/download?force=true"};
    
    const int num_threads = 4;
    std::thread threads[num_threads];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < num_threads; i++)
    {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(500));
        threads[i] = std::thread(win_downLoad, urlVector);
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < num_threads; i++)
    {
        if (threads[i].joinable())
        {
            threads[i].join();
        }
    }

    std::cout << num_threads << " threads have been worked successfully.\n";
    return 0;
}
```

**So, The essence of my question is, how can I use C++ code to multithread
downloading multiple files to a specified directory on a Win10 OS?**

Comment: Can't you generate a distinct file name for each image? E.g. `test1.jpg`, `test2.jpg` and so on. I fail to quite grasp the nature of the difficulty.

Comment: Because I want to download pictures with multithreads, so I can't generate a distinct file name for each image. If change my download code from `std::string savepath = "C:\\tmp\\"` to `std::string savepath = "C:\\tmp\\test.jpg" + i`, it will not work.

Comment: You know how many images each thread has to download. Just pass to each thread an integer to start numbering from, and arrange those starting numbers so they don't overlap. E.g. thread 1 starts numbering from 1; if it's given, say, 10 images to download, just have thread 2 start numbering from 11.

Comment: Thanks! Your comment has inspired me.
Let me look into it again.@IgorTandetnik

Comment: Yes，I'm already aware of the situation you're talking about. So I have nothing better to do now.@Ron

Comment: @Ron your comment help me a lot!! Thanks!!

Comment: Now, I simplly solve my problem by change my code from `std::string savepath = "C:\\tmp\\";` to `std::string savepath = "C:\\tmp\\test" + std::to_string(j) + std::string( ".jpg") ;`.It seems that the problem is that I am directly using an implicit conversion from int to std::string, when I should have used an explicit conversion.

Comment: can also use ```thread ID``` as prefix and counter from 1 as a suffix for each thread, by this you can also able to identify the file from which thread it is downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than passing whole urlVector to win_download function pass a part of it , divide the parts among the threads.